# Das Wesen vs. die Wesenheit

Tags: meaning, difference, german-to-english

Ich habe eine Frage über dem Unterschied zwischen dem Begriff des Wesens und der Wesenheit. Ich würde mich freuen, wenn ein Muttersprachler mit den Beispielen oder einer Beschreibung des Wortgefühls den erklären könnte. Sowohl die alltägliche Bedeutung als auch die philosophische sind für mich interessant. Vergleiche mit Englisch oder Russisch würden auch hilfreich.

Vielen Dank!

Comment: Möglicherweise äußer ich jetzt eine persönliche Meinung denn das sind keine alltäglichen Begrifflichkeiten: Wesen = essence, Wesenheit = entity. Die Summe alle Merkmale sind das Wesen, ihre spezifische Ausprägung machen eine Wesenheit aus. Andere mögen das aber genau andersherum sehen, weshalb man vor der Anwendung solcher Begriffe gerade in der Philosophie sie recht genau definieren sollte. Bin mir unsicher ob das als Antwort ausreicht ...

Comment: Ich denke, "*die Wesenheit*" ist eine Begriff, der im alltäglichen Sprachgebrauch nicht oder sehr selten benutzt wird. Aus meiner Sicht sind das Synonyme, und "*die Wesenheit*" ist eine gehobene Variante. Siehe https://www.dwds.de/wb/Wesenheit Mit dem Sprachgebrauch im Bereich der Philosophie kenne ich mich nicht aus.

Comment: Als Muttersprachler kann ich bestätigen, daß eine *alltägliche* Bedeutung nicht existiert :-)

Comment: Willkommen bei German.SE. Welche Begriffsdefinitionen sind bei der eigenen Recherche gefunden worden? (= daran könnte sich zeigen, wo es "formal" Überschneidung oder Abgrenzung gibt)

Comment: Meiner Erfahrung nach wird "Wesen" im Alltag vor allem im Sinne von "essence", "nature", "character" verwendet. Die Bedeutung "being", "entity" gibt es auch, die kommt aber eher in speziellen Kontexten wie der Science Fiction vor. "Wesenheit" findet man meiner Erfahrung nach im Alltag nahezu gar nicht. Dieser Begriff kommt eigentlich nur in den eben angesprochenen speziellen Kontexten wie SF, Philosophie, Religion vor. Dabei würde ich "Wesenheit" als stärker höflich oder ehrerbietig als das eher neutrale "Wesen" einordnen.

Comment: Whatta ya know? The morons struck again. If you don't understand a question, close it for being unclear. Great!! Don't ya just love these guys? OK, so to give an answer anyway; What you need to notice is. Whereas "Wesen" is some kind of Wesen, "Wesenheit" is some kind of -heit. It carries the nature of nature, but isn't itself nature. Like in "Nature" versus "Naturally". English offers options German lacks, like "Nature-ish", so Germans invent words like Wesenheit and spend the rest of their lives fighting over what it means. Wesen characterizes, Wesenheit captures what makes it one.

Answer (score 0):

Laut Duden sind diese Begriffe Synonyme. Ich habe auch in philosophischen Wörterbüchern gesucht und habe nur "Wesen" gefunden und nicht "Wesenheit". Ein bisschen Kontext wäre vielleicht hilfreich :D
In der Alltagssprache habe ich nur "das Wesen" gehört, kommt allerdings auch nicht häufig vor.